# Where can I find good sample code for iPhone game?

Tags: iphone

Where can I find good sample code for iPhone game?

Answer (score 4):

Check this thread: [Are there any Open-source iPhone games around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365947/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-games-around)

There are some open source projects out there, as well as open source game development frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few complete game sources over at [Binpress](http://www.binpress.com) -

- [Line-drawing game starterkit](http://www.binpress.com/app/linedrawing-game-starterkit/551)
- [BATAK duel source-code package](http://www.binpress.com/app/batak-duel-source-code-package/550)